# Order of execution in ggvis and reactive slider input shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I create very simple shiny app with one reactive widgets `sliderInput`. The solution allow me to manipulate a scale of y-axis. But when I set slider between 0 and 0.3 and then I change product e.g. P1->P3 the `sliderInput` widget automatically comes back to the original range (i.e. 0 and 1). App works fine, but I noticed that when I change a product with manipulated range, the first step is to draw a plot with manipulated y-axis and after that plot includes original range in y-axis. It looks quite ugly especially in more complex app. How can I change the order of execution, i.e. the first would be changing range of y-axis and then generate a plot?

**global.R**

```
library(dplyr)

prod <- c('P1','P2','P3')
level <- c('L1','L2','L3')
part <- c('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5')

set.seed(123)
module1_df <- data.frame(prod = sample(prod,300, replace = T), 
                         value = runif(300,0,0.3))

module1_df <- as.data.frame(module1_df %>% 
                                    group_by(prod) %>% 
                                    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
                                    arrange(prod, id))
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

ui <- navbarPage(
                title = '',
                tabPanel("Module 1",
                         selectInput('prod', '', prod),
                         uiOutput('in_value'),
                         ggvisOutput('plot_show')
                )
        )
)

server <- (function(input, output) {

        data_0 <- reactive({
                df <- module1_df %>% 
                        filter(prod == input$prod)
        })

        output$in_value <- renderUI({
                df2 <- data_0()
                var <- 'value'
                min_value <- min(df2[,var])
                sliderInput('value','',min = round(min_value,0), 
                            max = 1, value = c(0,1), step = 0.1)
        })

        data <- reactive({
                df3 <- data_0()
                if (!is.null(input$value)) {
                        df3 <- df3 %>% 
                                filter(df3[['value']] >= input$value[1] & 
                                       df3[['value']] <= input$value[2])
                }
                return(df3)

        })
        plot <- reactive({

                withProgress('', value = 0, {
                        y_min <- input$value[1]
                        y_max <- input$value[2]

                        plot <- data() %>% 
                                ggvis(~id, ~value) %>% 
                                layer_points() %>% 
                                scale_numeric('y',domain = c(y_min, y_max))

                        Sys.sleep(0.5)
                })
                return(plot)
        })

        plot %>% bind_shiny('plot_show')

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing an `invalidateLater` for 1 second in your reactive plot command will make the renderer wait just enough for the slider to reinitialize. I also changed the `Sys.sleep` to a much shorter time, so the re-plot delay is almost imperceptible

```
# note the added 'session' argument
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_0 <- reactive({
    df <- module1_df %>% 
      filter(prod == input$prod)
  })

  output$in_value <- renderUI({
    df2 <- data_0()
    var <- 'value'
    min_value <- min(df2[,var])
    sliderInput('value','', min = round(min_value ,0), 
                max = 1, value = c(0, 1), step = 0.1)
  })


  data <- reactive({
    df3 <- data_0()
    if (!is.null(input$value)) {
      df3 <- df3 %>% 
        filter(df3[['value']] >= input$value[1] & 
                 df3[['value']] <= input$value[2])
    }
    return(df3)

  })



  plot <- reactive({

   invalidateLater(1000, session)

    withProgress('', value = 0, {
      y_min <- input$value[1]
      y_max <- input$value[2]

      plot <- isolate(data()) %>% 
        ggvis(~id, ~value) %>% 
        layer_points() %>% 
        scale_numeric('y', domain = c(y_min, y_max))

        Sys.sleep(0.01)
    })
    return(plot)
  })

  plot %>% bind_shiny('plot_show')

}
```

Comment: I used Sys.sleep() only to present the problem (in order to be more visible). Besides, it is fantastic! I am not aware of that function. Thanks!

Comment: whoops, the `isolate(data())` is necessary, the others not. It is preventing the plot from evaluating on the change of `input$prod` nested in `data_0` and instead reacts on the `input$value` change.

Comment: It seems withProgress is also unnecessary because it cause never ending loop of loading.